# Can a report exempt someone from owning a firearm in the U.S.?

Tags: united-states, firearms

I was reading a thread on the social media site Reddit and the OP discussed how he found out that he was unable to purchase a firearm with no reason given.

Though he had no criminal record and no involuntarily commission, he had been reported by a forensic psychiatrist to the Met Police (he's a dual UK/US citizen) for homicidal ideation and he figures that when he moved back to the U.S., the police detectives also informed the FBI who noted and it came up on a background check.

But I've heard that reports from the public/doctors aren't enough to bar someone from owning a gun and I'm thinking it may be a false story. What is true?

Answer (score 3):

What is true is that [18 USC 922(d)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/922) says

> It shall be unlawful for any person to sell or otherwise dispose of
> any firearm or ammunition to any person knowing or having reasonable
> cause to believe that such person...(4) has been adjudicated as a
> mental defective or has been committed to any mental institution

"Adjudicated as a mental defective" is then defined in [27 CFR 478.11](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/27/478.11)

> A determination by a court, board, commission, or other lawful
> authority that a person, as a result of marked subnormal intelligence,
> or mental illness, incompetency, condition, or disease:
>
> (1) Is a danger to himself or to others; or
>
> (2) Lacks the mental capacity to contract or manage his own affairs.

A forensic psychiatrist is not a general "member of the public", so it is credible to consider one to be a "lawful authority". No aspect of the law limits *whose* law gives the lawful authority his authority: of course more details on the psychiatrist would be necessary to determine that this is a proper application of the restriction.