# Will my friend be unable to purchase a gun in the U.S. for hunting after a report by a psychiatrist?

Tags: fbi

My friend is half-British and half-American. When he was 18, he smoked too much cannabis and went into a psychotic break. He started talking about how voices were commanding him to commit a terrorist attack. His psychiatrist reported him to the Met Police who reported him to Special Branch.

Now he's fine, off drugs, not psychotic and has got a job in the U.S. but he fears that his ability to get a gun for hunting will be impeded if UK intelligence reports him to the FBI.

The regulations of gun laws say that someone who has been involuntarily committed is ineligible but would getting a report by a psychiatrist qualify as that?

Comment: This seems nearly the same as [your previous question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/67709/can-a-report-exempt-someone-from-owning-a-firearm-in-the-u-s?rq=1)?

Comment: There must be a reason why the OP asked this question despite their first question having an answer. The duplicate vote appears to be premature.

Comment: Why not just try to buy a gun in a context where he will be subject to a background check, and see whether he is allowed to complete the purchase?

Comment: @phoog you may want to consult the passage from the USC in the answer to the question linked by Nate Eldredge, for an answer to your question.  A background check may not detect that the criterion has been met, but it would appears that it has been met anyway.

Comment: @grovkin the purchaser of a firearm won't fall afoul of that particular passage.  It is directed at the person who sells or otherwise distributes the firearm.

Comment: @phoog agreed.  But once that is established, the ramifications for the buyer (who has caused a seller to commit a felony through a lie or an omission) are almost certain to entail some sort of criminal culpability.  Although I can't think of what that would be *exactly*.  Maybe if this question is reworded along those lines, it could become an interesting separate inquiry.